# Replace elements of numpy.ndarray specified with ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D `numpy.ndarray()` and indices to be replaced.

```py
idx = np.array([[1, 0],
                [2, 1],
                [2, 3],])
array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Which I want to have is like following array.

```py
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Elements where specified by `idx` in the array is replaced with an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to index the `array` by 2D array `idx`:

```py
array[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = 1
print(array)
```

Prints:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by looping on indices array and do manual set to value at each specified index or directly like this `array[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = 1`.

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.array([[1, 0],
                [2, 1],
                [2, 2]])

array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
                  
array[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = 1
print(array)
```